# Moving pins on bing maps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I am using bing maps on windows phone 8.1. I am using Image object as pin.

```
            var img = new Image();
            img.Width = 40;
            img.Height = 160;
            //img.Margin = new Thickness(-100,-100,0,0);
            switch (location.Type)
            {
                case 1:
                    {

                        var bmp = new BitmapImage();
                        bmp.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/pin_moder@2x.png");
                        img.Source = bmp;
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    {
                        var bmp = new BitmapImage();
                        bmp.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/pin_roza@2x.png");
                        img.Source = bmp;
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                default:
                    {
                        var bmp = new BitmapImage();
                        bmp.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/pin_rumen@2x.png");
                        img.Source = bmp;
                        break;
                    }
            }
            MapControl.Children.Add(img);

            var position = new BasicGeoposition();
            position.Latitude = location.Latitude;
            position.Longitude = location.Longtitude;

            MapControl.SetLocation(img, new Geopoint(position));
            MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(img, new Point(0.5,0.5));
        }
```

This is the code that handles pin adding.
However, when pins are placed on map, and I move around the map, pins are "shaking" (moving left to right and top to bottom a bit) when moving around the map. When I stop moving around the map, this shaky thing goes away.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a known issue when overlaying XAML controls on top of the WP8.1 map control. Note that WP8.1 maps are not Bing Maps, but HERE maps.